# Раскрытие макросов

Tags: c++, макросы

Есть маленький вопрос по раскрытиям макросов.

Например, этот код работает:

```
#define DEF_STRUCT(name, type) struct name {using t = type;};
DEF_STRUCT(hah, int)
```

И это:

```
#define DEF_STRUCT(name, type) struct name {using t = type;};
#define BUILD_STRUCT_1(name, type) DEF_STRUCT(name, type)
BUILD_STRUCT_1(heh, char)
```

А вот этот ругается (*Требуется спецификатор*):

```
#define DEF_STRUCT(name, type) struct name {using t = type;};
#define BUILD_STRUCT_1(name, type) DEF_STRUCT(name, type)
#define BUILD_STRUCT_2(name, type, ...) DEF_STRUCT(name, type) BUILD_STRUCT_1(__VA_ARGS__)
BUILD_STRUCT_2(lol, bool, kek, unsigned) // Извини, не хочу работать
```

Вопрос: как он раскрывается и что следует поменять чтобы заработало как хотелось (Объявление 2-х структур подряд)?

Comment: Глюк MSVC, очевидно.

Comment: @AnT, на разных компьютерах? Я конечно попробую 17 версию, но не уверен. + он не компилится.

Comment: При чем здесь компьютеры? Это баг компилятора. Присутствует и в VS2017.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Код прекрасно компилируется GCC. В MSVC он не компилируется из-за нестандартного поведения препроцессора. Эту разницу в поведении препроцессора можно проиллюстрировать примером без `__VA_ARGS__`

```
#define M2(a, b)
#define M1(x) M2(x) /* <- Считается ошибкой в MSVC */
#define A 1, 2
M1(A)
```

В качестве workaround можно предложить

```
#define BUILD_STRUCT_2(name, type, name2, ...) \
    DEF_STRUCT(name, type) BUILD_STRUCT_1(name2, __VA_ARGS__)
```

или более общее

```
#define FIRST(x, ...) x
#define TAIL(x, ...) __VA_ARGS__

#define BUILD_STRUCT_2(name, type, ...) \
  DEF_STRUCT(name, type) BUILD_STRUCT_1(FIRST(__VA_ARGS__), TAIL(__VA_ARGS__))
```

Хотя не совсем понятно, зачем здесь `...` и `__VA_ARGS__` вообще.

Comment: Это просто тестовый набросок. А так type мне не нужен там. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, просто мета информации о структуре классов пока нет. Так что с помощью смеси именованного тупла и макросов храню слепок части бд для рантайма.

Comment: Только вот это решение работает только для 2-х.

Comment: @MrBin: Ну нам отсюда не видно, что там у вас творится "не для 2-x"...

Comment: Это MSVS шалит. Для 3-х и более возрастает количество "необходимых" параметров для раскрытия следующего макроса. Иначе компилятор не пускает. Мб, есть у вас вариант? Чтоб примерно следующая коснтрукция `#define PKS(...) STRUCTS(__VA_ARGS__) tagged_tuple<__VA_ARGS__> PKS;` создавала структуры на каждое имя (type игнорируется), и в конце создается tuple.